# Gitlab rest api file content "Invalid character in input stream." bash

Tags: curl, gitlab, base64

I spent half hour figuring out why base64 decoding is not working.

Scenario:

Reading file content from Gitlab using `curl` and decoding base64 string.

Did this:

```
curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/123/repository/files/README%2Emd | jq '.content' | base64 -d
```

Output

```
Invalid character in input stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason: quotes added by jq.

Fix:

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/123/repository/files/README%2Emd | jq -r '.content' | base64 -d
```

`-r` flag for raw output